# Folder Selection types Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonOpenFileDialog to textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need type selected folder to a textbox but when I select folder it types this `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonOpenFileDialog`

My Code is:

```
CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();

dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
{
    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(dialog);
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString(dialog)` (or `dialog.ToString()`) returns the name of the Type. -- What if you write `dialog` then enter a dot an see what Intellisense comes up with?

Comment: textBox1.Text = dialog.FileName;

Comment: The microsof.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs have a bug. when you click on his border you can't select or do anything.
The only way is press alt+tab keys or call task manager and so on.
Seems looks like a lost focused behavior .